# Rails: NoMethodError for module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, controller

I've an `AuthenticatorService` module located in the file `app/services/authenticator_service.rb`.

This module looks like this:

```
module AuthenticatorService

  # authenticate user with its email and password
  # in case of success, return signed in user
  # otherwise, throw an exception
  def authenticate_with_credentials(email, password)
    user = User.find_by_email(email)
    raise "Invalid email or password" if user.nil? or not user.authenticate password

    return user
  end

  # some other methods...

end
```

I currently use this module in my `SessionsController`.

```
class V1::SessionsController < ApplicationController
  # POST /sessions
  # if the credentials are valid, sign in the user and return the auth token
  # otherwise, return json data containing the error
  def sign_in
    begin
      user = AuthenticatorService.authenticate_with_credentials params[:email], params[:password]
      token = AuthenticatorService::generate_token user

      render json: { success: true, user: user.as_json(only: [:id, :first_name, :last_name, :email]), token: token }
    rescue Exception => e
      render json: { success: false, message: e.message }, status: 401
    end
  end
end
```

`SessionsController` is in the namespace `V1` because it is located in `app/controllers/v1/sessions_controller.rb` but that's not the problem here.

The problem is that, when I call the route corresponding to `SessionsController::sign_in`, I go the following error: `undefined method 'authenticate_with_credentials' for AuthenticatorService:Module`.

I can't understand why I get this error in development and production environments for multiple reasons:

- When I add debug information, I can see that the AuthenticatorService is loaded and accessible from the controller
- Moreover, when I display the public instance methods, `authenticate_with_credentials` is listed in the result (`puts AuthenticatorService.public_instance_methods`)
- In my test, this controller is tested and everything works as expected...

Maybe someone could give me some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your problem, add

```
module_function :authenticate_with_credentials
```

declaration in your `AuthenticatorService` module.

`AuthenticatorService.public_instance_methods` contains this method, because instances which include this module will have this method available. But `AuthenticatorService` itself is not an instance.

Comment: Good! I've also just seen `def AuthenticatorService.authenticate_with_credentials`.

Comment: @SimonNinon have a loot at this tpp http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/module_function